# Find all the open sets in the smallest topologies on $\mathbb{N}$.

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathbb{N}$ be the set of positive integers. Find explicitly all the open sets in the smallest topologies on $\mathbb{N}$ for which each of the following is a collection of the open sets.

a) $\mathbb{N}$ and $\phi$

b) $\mathbb{N}$, {1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}

c) $\mathbb{N}$, {1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {1, 4, 7}

I don't really understand how or what I'm really doing here. This concept has been pretty confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if $X$ is a set and $S\subseteq X$, then $\{\varnothing, S, X\}$ is a topology for $X$.
Also if $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $X$ then $\{\varnothing, A,A\cap B, B,A\cup B, X\}$ is a topology
for $X$.

You can finish the last by considering $\{\varnothing, A,B,C,A\cap B,A\cap C,etc.,\dots, X\}$

You need all finite intersections and union.

Comment: Isn't $A \cup B$ also a member of a topology for $X$?

Comment: Yes, it is. fixed

Comment: So then, for the first one, it is simply $\{\phi, \mathbb{N}\}$, correct?

Comment: Yes. (It is called the indiscrete topology)

Comment: The second one would be $\{\phi, \{1,2\}, \{3,4,5\}, \{1,2,3,4,5\}, \mathbb{N}\}$.

Comment: Yep. You get the idea.

Comment: Thanks, Bryan. I get it now.

Comment: In general, you need all *arbitrary* unions. But in your case, you only start off with a finite number of open sets.

Comment: So, then, I assume for c, that means I'll have to include $\{1,2\} \cup \{3,4,5\} \cup \{1,4,7\}$.

Comment: Yes. You need *all* unions that you can create, and all finite intersections you can create. If you get new sets, be sure to go back and create any new unions and any new intersection that you need.

Comment: Got it, many thanks.